# crystal report - Subtract result for each item

Tags: crystal-reports

On Crystal Report, I want to show 
`My_Qty`, which is `{Table.1st_Qty}-{Table.2nd_qty}`, for each item.

My desired outcome is

```
Item 1   5  0  5(My_Qty_1)
Item 2   6  0  6(My_Qty_2)
```

But my current CR shows

```
Item 1   5  0  11
Item 2   6  0  11
```

Is there anyway that I can adjust `{Table.1st_Qty}-{Table.2nd_qty}` to print out what I want?

I have tried 'Running Total Fields' but no luck. I've been googling around but can't find an answer for my case. 
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [whileprintingrecords](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=182644):

It will do sum while reading data from start to end.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for the reply. Just curious, why do i need to use 'sum' in my case?

Comment: And I've been closely looking in to the link you have shared, but I'm having trouble with understanding it..

Comment: Sorry for keep bothering you but the link you shared is irrelevant to my question. Because the website is specifically about 'sum'. They do subtract some of their values but the goal itself is 'summing' the value from a function.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong :) Thank you so much!

Comment: do not rely on the sum.. Just stay focus on whileprintingrecords because that is you need. The important is you have to learn on how to use it.